# Problems with acm bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib, acm

I am using acmsmall.zip from  http://www.acm.org/publications/article-templates/acm-latex-style-guide and my bibliography looks weird :(. I am attaching a minimal example to highlight my problems. In this example I am using natbib but I have tried cite package as well and the results weren't any different.

```
    \documentclass[prodmode,acmtecs]{acmsmall} 
    \usepackage{flushend,amsmath,graphicx,booktabs}
    %\usepackage[obeyspaces,hyphens]{url}
    \usepackage{natbib}
    %\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}
    \usepackage[]{caption}
    \usepackage[]{subcaption}
    \captionsetup{compatibility=false}
    \usepackage[]{algorithm2e,algorithmic}
    \usepackage{xspace,balance}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \urlstyle{sf}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \begin{document}
    \title{A Multifrequency MAC Specially Designed for Wireless Sensor Network Applications}
    \maketitle
    \section{Introduction}
    Using \cite{monte-carlo} and \cite{backblaze2014}.
    \bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format-Journals}
    {\footnotesize
    \bibliography{paper}}
    \end{document}
```

Running this code produces

A Multifrequency MAC Specially Designed for Wireless Sensor
Network Applications

1. INTRODUCTION

Using [?? mon] and [bac 2014].

REFERENCES

Monte Carlo method. (????).

2014. Hard Drive Reliability Update. (2014). https://www.backblaze.com/blog/
      hard-drive-reliability-update-september-2014/.

I have couple of problems here.
1. I need numbers in front of references to show their position in the bibliography.
2. I do not want year to appear twice in the reference. 
3. Do I need to have year and author name for each bib entry? Is this why those question marks appear in the reference entry?

The corresponding entries in the bibliography are

```
    @article{monte-carlo,
    title={{Monte Carlo method}},
    note={\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method}}
    }

    @article{backblaze2014,
    title={{Hard Drive Reliability Update}},
    year={2014},
    note={\url{https://www.backblaze.com/blog/hard-drive-reliability-update-september-2014/}}
    }
```

Comment: Using the entry type `@article` seems inappropriate for the two entries you've shown. The entry type `@article` has `author`, `journal`, and `year` among the *required* fields. I'd use the `@misc` entry type instead.

Comment: Wikipedia has a citation export for Bibtex that you can use. It will set the author to `Wikipedia`, which is quite strange. I suggest to change it to `Wikipedia contributors`.

Comment: Citing your sources is essential. Maybe you can find some better sources than Wikipedia? Where does Wikipedia take its information from?

Answer (score 1):

This style seems to use author names and years in the reference abbreviations, i.e., something like `[Smith94]` instead of `[1]`. If that was the case, the weirdness would result because you do not supply authors (`author = {...}`) in your BibTeX entries.

On their website, it says:

> The in-text citation style is as follows: For parenthetical citations we enclose the last name of the first author and year of publication, thus: [Burando 2007];

Thus, you probably just need to supply author and year in the BibTeX and get good-looking citations.